# Publish asp.net 5.0 project to IIS fails with: The runtime was not packaged with the application

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a ASP.NET 5.0 Website Project.

I published the project to a folder on my pc.

[image]

I created in IIS a website pointing to the physical folder: wwwroot

When I go in IIS to "Browse website" and the Browser opens on localhost I see this error:

```
Unable to find the runtime directory 'C:\TGB.Published\TGB.Backend\wwwroot\..\approot\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta5'. 
Possible causes:
1. The runtime was not packaged with the application.
2. The packaged runtime architecture is different from the application pool architecture.
```

When I look in the published folder approot\runtimes there is the folder dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5 with content.

But I am confused why approot is mentioned under the wwwroot? As you see on my screenshot they are both on the same hierarchy. Why does it look for approot under wwwroot?

My Application Pool for the created Website in IIS is .NET 4.0.

Comment: Note that the `..` in the path would be where there is the going up the folder structure though I'd question if you have the right folder structure as going up from the root could be a bad thing in some places I'd imagine.

Comment: This is the default folder structure. I havent change anything. That should work out of the box. If not I better drop that crap then ;-)

Comment: It seems this link: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#iis-server-configuration has a bad description about "wwwroot" and which one is meant because there also exist the inetpub/wwwroot. I have pointed my IIS website now to the parent folder of both deployed folders (wwwroot and approot) and the exception is gone. I am following this good tut now: https://tndhuy.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/publish-asp-net-5-app-and-run-in-iis-8-5-using-cmd-vs2015-rc/

Comment: The above wordpress tut is also ambiguous. You do not really know which folder to put where that the index.html is shown...

Comment: With that link I made it work that the layout.cshtml is shown under the root url with full IIS: http://blog.winhost.com/vnext-the-next-generation-of-asp-net/ , my problem was also that I deployed x86 clr beta 5 not the x64 because I run 64bit Win 10. :-)

Comment: Whilte not a good answer, I still recommend updating to beta8. This will allow you to set the IIS application pool to not use any managed code and avoids tracking down problems that have been solved since.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error. For me the issue was with the Target DNX Version. I had the default option selected x86 and changing it to x64 solved it!

[image]

Check your application pool in IIS. If it does not have 32-Bit enabled then you need to publish in 64-Bit.

[image]